# Convert a Php array to json format

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb

I have an array like this,

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => naveen
    )

    Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => bos
    )
```

I am using a csv upload to insert data's to the mongodb

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {           
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);         
        echo "</pre>";
}
```

i want to convert the array into a json format, i have tried the `json_encode($data);` but it is coming like this

```
["1","naveen"]

["2","bos"]
```

What i want to do make this array as json encoded format

Comment: Show us how you're using `json_encode`.

Comment: Where i will read the csv file. i have a upload.php there i write the html form and action to a slim function. inside that function i would add the read the csv and inert to mongo db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes finally make it work.

```
        $keys="";
        $result=array();
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if($keys==""){
                $keys = $data;
            }else{
                $output = array();          
                for ($i=0; $i <count($keys) ; $i++) { 
                    $output[$keys[$i]]=$data[$i];

                }
                array_push($result, $output);
            }

        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(json_encode($result));
        echo "</pre>";
```

Got Output Like below

```
[{"id":"1","name":"naveen"},{"id":"2","name":"bos"}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to put it all into *one* array and then json encode it:

```
$array = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {           
    $array[] = $data;
}
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Please spread the word that the reverse `json_decode` is the usual answer to "how do I write this query in PHP".

Comment: Hi John Conde Thankyou for your reply i am getting like this [["1","naveen"]][["1","naveen"],["2","bos"]], is it possible to make the array {"1":"naveen"},{"2":"bos"} like this?

Comment: Try casting the arrays to objects: `$array[] = (object) $data;`

Comment: I have tried this some changes but not exact one [{"0":"1","1":"naveen"},{"0":"2","1":"bos"}]

Comment: That is how it will look because it is in one array, hence the array syntax around the objects.

Comment: ["1","naveen"],["2","bos"] is this possible?